# How can I iterate a function up to a certain integer and plot the resulting functions to a single graph

Tags: plotting, functions

Firstly I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Say I have a function:

```
f[x, a] := x^2 + a
```

Is it possible to plot a single graph of all f[x, a] against x with a taking integer values up to some number N and x between -10 and 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[Table[x^2 + a, {a, 0, 5}], 
    {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you could up-vote my answer by clicking the up triangle, or accepting my answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: I have now, I had to wait 8 minutes. I cant up-vote sorry, I dont have enough reputation.